# Help translating 系 and ネタ this sentence

Tags: meaning, translation, slang, suffixes

> こいつはこっち**系**の**ネタ**にとにかく弱いのだ

The definition I found of 系 (system) doesn't seem to fit here. What does that mean?

As for ネタ, I know it can mean ''joke'' but is it really what it means here? In the official translation, this sentence has been translated as ''She's especially weak to this sort of talk.''

Comment: It feels slang-y, but consider the term 渋谷系 when talking about music -- here, 系 takes on the meaning of "style" or "type", not "system". Maybe it's this kind of usage when referencing こっち系, or, "this type" or "this style".

Answer (score 2):

As psosuna notes in the comment, 系 here means something more like "style, type, sort of thing".

ネタ derives as slang from 種【たね】, and originally referred to "seed" as in "raw material from which to make something else".  I think ネタ still has this meaning, in addition to the broader sense of just "stuff".

Looking at your sample translation, I see that you may have misparsed とにかく.  This isn't とくに ("especially"), but rather its own word とにかく ("anyway").

So putting all that together:

> こいつはこっち**系**の**ネタ**に**とにかく**弱いのだ
>     She's weak **anyway** when it comes to this **sort** of **stuff**.

Comment: 「とにかく」って、口語的に、「すごく」みたいな意味で使いますよね？「[とにかく強い](https://www.google.co.uk/search?ei=URIWWpvkNMHz8QXoxb8Y&btnG=Search&q="とにかく強い")」とか。。　「特に」みたいな意味でも使いますよね？　「・・・[にとにかく強い](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q="にとにかく強い")」とか。。

Comment: @Chocolate、そうですか。初耳（読んでますので、「初目」？）です。リンクされたページを読んだら、事例からは「とくに」の意味合いはどうか見ていませんが、[このページ](https://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AB%E3%81%8B%E3%81%8F)に書いてある説明のほうに馴染んでます。ですが、日本に住んだのはもう数年前のことですし、この点は譲ります。もしかしたら、この使い方は比較的に新しいのでしょうか、それとも地域によるものですか。

Comment: なんの文脈もなしに「彼はとにかく優秀でして…」などと言えますね。"in every way" が近いかもしれません。やや口語的ですが俗語というほどではないですし、新しい言い方でもないと思います。

Comment: @naruto、ありがとうございます。辞書などの資料を参照してみますとこの意味合いが載っていませんので、俗語か地域的な言い方かと思いました。載っていないのはなぜでしょう。

Comment: ほんまですねえ。。。いろいろ辞書見てみたんですけど、載ってないですねえ。。